# Does a filter need to be applied before running cross validation in WEKA

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, classification

I want to run n fold cross validation on some classifiers I am using. I found example code on the [WEKA Wiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code) (here is the [WekaDemo.java](http://weka.wikispaces.com/file/view/WekaDemo.java)) but this applies a filter before running the validation. Does this always need to be done or is this not required?

Here is the section of code:

```
  /**
   * runs 10fold CV over the training file
   */
  public void execute() throws Exception {
    // run filter
    m_Filter.setInputFormat(m_Training);
    Instances filtered = Filter.useFilter(m_Training, m_Filter);

    // train classifier on complete file for tree
    m_Classifier.buildClassifier(filtered);

    // 10fold CV with seed=1
    m_Evaluation = new Evaluation(filtered);
    m_Evaluation.crossValidateModel(
        m_Classifier, filtered, 10, m_Training.getRandomNumberGenerator(1));
  }
```

Also is this an acceptable way of evaluating performance of a classifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider this bad practise. If the filter depends on/uses class information, then the cross-validation estimate will be (potentially very) optimistically biased, and therefore probably useless. For an extreme example think about adding a copy of the class-attribute to the data. In almost all cases you will be better off and safer if you use weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier there is an example on how to use it on the same Wiki page you cite.

cheers, Bernhard

Comment: I don't actually want to use any filter. I'm new to weka so wanted to make sure I was OK just using the crossValidateModel method without filtering. Can I do that?